# fancybox and IE issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

Can someone explain to me, why this isn't working?

**app.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {

    jQuery("#case_questions_1_submit").fancybox({
            type: 'inline',
            href: '#pc_check_overlay',
            wrapCSS: 'overlay_pccheck',
            autoSize: false,
            height: 315,
            width: 595

    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<button class="small btn_pccheck" id="case_questions_1_submit" type="submit">BUTTON <i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large icon"></i></button>
```

**Error Message:**
German:
SCRIPT438: Das Objekt unterstützt die Eigenschaft oder Methode "fancybox" nicht 
app.js, Zeile 12 Zeichen 2

English:
SCRIPT438: The object does not support property or method 'fancybox'
app.js, Row 12 Char 2

Row 12 is this row:

```
jQuery("#case_questions_1_submit").fancybox({
```

It's in IE10 and 9... I don't know what's wrong. jQuery Version is 1.9.0

Thanks!

Comment: Meaning that fancybox plugin is not loaded at time you are trying to use it

Comment: Ok but I load it like this 1.jQuery, 2. Fancybox js and css, 3. app.js

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I checked the order of the plugins / js scripts and I placed the app.js script into the header (instead of the footer) and now it works like a charm.
Thanks to A.Wolff!